# creating simple shopping cart using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to crate a very simple `shopping cart`
I am using a `session` and `array` to add the items to an `array` and save the `array` into `session` and display the items in this `session` properly like 
item 1 name -- price
item 2 name -- price
and then take the total to my payment method.

here is the code I am using.

```
 print_r($_SESSION['cart']);


if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    //header("Location:?pid=18&pl=" . $pl);
    $getData = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id=?');
    $getData->bind_param('i', $pl);
    if ($getData->execute()) {
        $res = $getData->get_result();
        if ($pn = $res->fetch_object()) {

            $item['name'] = $pn->plan_name;
            $item['price'] = $pn->price_dollar;
            if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Issues**
`( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cart`

**EDIT**

this is what I end with

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $c) {
        echo $c['name'] . '<br />';
        echo $c['price'] . '<br />';
        echo '<a href="?pid=17&rc=' . $c['code'] . '">Remove item</a><br />';
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    //header("Location:?pid=18&pl=" . $pl);
    if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
        $getData = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id=?');
        $getData->bind_param('i', $pl);
        if ($getData->execute()) {
            $res = $getData->get_result();
            if (($pn = $res->fetch_object()) !== null) {
                $proCode = range(1, 100);
                shuffle($proCode);

                $item['name'] = $pn->plan_name;
                $item['price'] = $pn->price_dollar;
                $item['code'] = $proCode;
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['rc']) && isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $rem = $_GET['rc'];
    if (($key = array_search($rem, $_SESSION['cart'])) !== false) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }
}
```

> but still the delete not working

Comment: Is there a session_start(); somewhere in your code ?

Comment: Yes there is one in the header I mean there is `header.php` which content the site headers and there is `session_start()` there

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_SESSION['cart'])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you're trying to print a variable that isn't set. Plus, with this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $item;
}
```

You'll never be able to add an item to your cart. My way to do this is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    $getData = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id=?');
    $getData->bind_param('i', $pl);
    if ($getData->execute()) {
        $res = $getData->get_result();
        if ($pn = $res->fetch_object()) {

            $item['name'] = $pn->plan_name;
            $item['price'] = $pn->price_dollar;

            $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, even if the `cart` key isn't set, it will be set anyway. By the same time, it will permit you to have multiple items in your cart.

**EDIT**: The next thing to do, if you want to show your items is the following:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $item) {
    echo "item $item->id $item->plan_name -- $item->price_dollar";
}
```

Comment: let me thank you first for this good answer, one more thing I need to understand how can I display the items in the session with formatted way like item 1 name -- price

Comment: can't I get this values from the session without depending on my database `$item->plan_name` and `$item->price_dollar`

Comment: Yeah, you could, by replacing the $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item by $_SESSION['cart'][]['my_custom_field'] = $item->whatever, but it seems a bit tricky.

Comment: I think something is wrong here in the Edit you said `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $item) {
    echo "item $item->id $item->plan_name -- $item->price_dollar";
}` but how can you used `plan_name` and `price_dollar` here? by the way I get this `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`

Comment: If you used the the previous comment, your variables are only accessible via `$item['my_custom_field']` since it's not an object anymore.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did that as `if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $c) {
        echo $c['name'] . '<br />';
        echo $c['price'] . '<br />';
        echo '<a href="?pid=17&rc=' . $c['code'] . '">Remove item</a><br />';
    }
}` and it solved the all issue

Comment: so if I need to remove one item now can I use this `if(($key = array_search($rc, $item)) !== false) {
    unset($item[$key]);
}` dose it help or there is something else I should do?

Comment: Yeah, it seems ok, the item would be deleted if it doesn't equals to false.

Comment: can you please take a look at my edit I try but something is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75280/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-edwin-dayot).